# Hosted Sole Solution through PHP-SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently doing a refactoring of payment system and I want to migrate to PayPal SDK since it provides much more flexibility, control and information that Hosted Sole Solution. I've run some test and it's everything I've expected until I've noticed that `$payment->getApproveLink()` returns URL to PayPal page that is not the same as on Hosted Sole Solution (one that my user gets redirected to once I submit POST form as per documentation for HSS). Is there a way to get best from both worlds?

HSS page does offer my user to pay with his credit card without creating PayPal account while the page I get through getApproveLink() forces paypal account (there's an option to create a new one ofc).

Anyone have any ideas how to keep flexibility of REST Api but keep my checkout page of HSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so while waiting for an answer I've continued to look for a solution. My main issue was what to do with txID that is returned by Hosted Sole Solution. Good news is that txID that you get from HSS is actually authorizationID so you can switch to REST API and do `Authorization::get($_GET['txID'], $apiContext);` and you'll get Authorization object.

With that you can capture, void etc.

P.S. Please don't really use $_GET['txID'] for security purpose - it was just an example.